# Prove or disprove: Finding a Continuously Differentiable Bijection between Open Sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

There exists a mapping $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^3)$ and open sets $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f|_U : U \rightarrow V$ is bijective and $(f|_U)^{-1} \in C^1(V, U)$.

$\textbf{My idea}:$

There is a function $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^3)$ and open sets $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f|_U : U \to V$ is bijective and $(f|_U)^{-1} \in C^1(V, U)$.

The given information states that there exists a function $f$ belonging to the class $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^3)$, which means that $f$ is a continuously differentiable function mapping from the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Furthermore, there are open sets $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f|_U$ is a bijection from $U$ to $V$. This means that each element in $U$ is uniquely mapped to an element in $V$ and vice versa.

Moreover, $(f|_U)^{-1} \in C^1(V, U)$, indicating that the inverse function of $f|_U$, denoted as $(f|_U)^{-1}$, is also continuously differentiable and maps from $V$ to $U$.

In summary, the given information states that there exists a continuously differentiable function $f$ that maps the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. This function $f$ is bijective on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Furthermore, the inverse function of $f|_U$, denoted as $(f|_U)^{-1}$, is also continuously differentiable and maps from $V$ to $U$.

Comment: That is not possible due to [the invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), no? Even in just continuous case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  particular dimensions $2$ and $3$ it is pretty easy to find the reason why it is not possible. WLOG we may assume that $V$ is an open ball. Fix a circle $D$  contained in $V.$ Let $C=f^{-1}(D).$ Then $f$ is a continuous bijection between $U\setminus C$ and $V\setminus D,$ whose inverse is continuous. The set $V\setminus D$ is connected, while $U\setminus C$ is not connected, which leads to a contradiction.